# How to make Fernet encryption produce the same ciphertext for the same data

Tags: encryption

I am using a cryptography library for Python and it provides [Fernet Module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken).

Now I have a plaintext to encrypt. It produces a ciphertext. Then I try to encrypt the same plaintext with the same key but the ciphertexts are different.

I need the ciphertext to be the same every time.
Do you know any way around this? Or maybe a different encryption technique?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need the ciphertext to be the same every time? Deterministic ciphertexts fail to satisfy the typical security goal for confidentiality, which is indistinguishability.

Comment: I am working on an experimental database. It's just a project that I run in my free time. Check it out: https://ipds.network/IPDS.pdf

Comment: Any reason you don't just page down the Python docs to _THE HAZARDOUS MATERIALS LAYER_?  You might be able to use types authenticated encryption with fixed IVs (careful), or failing that, simply AES-some-mode-thing.  Do you have any authentication issues in space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a **deterministic authenticated cipher**, or DAE, *deterministic authenticated encryption*, which has the property that an adversary can always tell when you have repeated messages, of course.

As far as I can tell, Fernet does not support any DAE.  Popular choices for DAE include SIV-type schemes like AES-SIV.  But you should have a good reason for using DAE first!  Most applications don't need it.